# Access values of fields not mapped to underline class with Symfony 2.1

Tags: forms, symfony-2.1

I have a Doctrine entity class mapped to a form class with Symfony 2.1 as usual. However, I also have a field that has the mapped option set to false and that is an hidden field. I want to access in the twig template the value of that field and also get the value inside the controller before saving the new entity to the database. Usually to access the value from twig I use

```
{{ form.vars.value.myfieldname }}
```

however in this case I don't understand why it throws an error:

```
Method "myfieldname" for object "MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity" does not exist
```

also, I don't understand how I could access the value of that field from the controller after binding the request to the form. Usually I could call myentity->getMyfield() and I would get the value but myfieldname now it not an entity property.

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient (it surely works on symfony 2.3):

```
{{ form.myfieldname.vars.data }}
```